# How to formally denote a bijection formula

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I'm learning set theory by doing exercises from a textbook that gives a high level overview of sets theory. Unfortunately it doesn't provide a lot of examples on the formal math language that I can use to formally denote bijection formulas.

My question is how to formally define a bijection formula between two sets without resorting to a lot of explanation. Take as an example the following exercise:

> Build a bijection between an interval $[0, 1]$ and half-interval $[0, 1)$

I solved this problem as follows:

---

Let's rewrite $M_1=[0, 1]$ as $M_1=C_1 + R_1 : R_1 = \{\frac{1}{n} \mid n \in \Bbb N \} \land C_1 = M_1 \setminus R_1$ and $M_2=[0, 1)$ as $M_2=C_2 + R_2 : R_2 = \{\frac{1}{n} \mid n \in (\Bbb N \setminus \{1\})\} \land C_2 = M_2 \setminus R_2$. A "plus" sign here means a union of non-intersecting sets.

It is easy to see that $C_1 = C_2$.
So a bijection would be a one-to-one mapping for elements of $C_1, C_2$.

For elements of $R_1, R_2$ bijection could be defined as follows:

$$g : R_1 \rightarrow R_2, g \left (\frac 1n \right ) = \frac{1}{n+1} \text{ for } n \in \Bbb N$$

and

$$g^{-1} : R_2 \rightarrow R_1, g^{-1}\left(\frac 1n \right) = \frac{1}{n-1} \text{ for } n \in (\Bbb N \setminus \{1\})$$

---

In the above proof I wanted to convey the idea that both intervals would have a common part  - i.e. either interval minus a set $R = \{x \mid x = \frac{1}{n}, n \in \Bbb N\}$ and then show a bijection for remaining elements, where remaining elements would be either interval minus set $R$.

Is there an easier or more accurate way to write the above?

Comment: I feel that this question is too basic so I perhaps could also use a recommendation on a textbook / article that details on the most common notation for defining the above. I read a few articles e.g. in wikipedia but I'm still confused on what formal bijection definition should look like.

Comment: I think there are at least a few other examples on this site of bijections between those two sets, but my memory is that this is a classic problem that is easy to state but has only ugly answers.

Comment: I was a bit dissatisfied to see that oftentimes (at least in the examples that I tried to learn from) it is defined as part plain English and part a math formula but I guess it'd be just easier to do it that way as it'd be easier to follow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bear in mind that the two spaces aren't homeomorphic (one is compact and the other is not), so there's no way to do this in a bicontinuous manner.  Indeed, since a continuous image of a compact set $([0, 1])$ achieves its maximum, there's no way to do this in a continuous manner.

The easiest way I can think of is this:  Let $\{q_n \mid n \in \Bbb N \}$ enumerate the rationals in $[0, 1)$.  (It's tedious, but you can come up with an express formula to do this if you want.)  Then define $f(1)= q_0, f(q_k)=q_{k+1}$ for the rationals, and let $f$ be the identity function on the irrationals.

Comment: Thank you! I'm still learning elementary sets theory so I think that homeomorphism would come shortly after that (groups?) but what you say makes sense to me.

If you don't mind me asking one more question: would it be accurate to write bijection definitions for $R_1, R_2$ (in terms of following proper mathematical notations) as I did it in my original question?

Comment: Yes, now that I'm following what you did, you have the same idea I was trying to convey, but you executed it more simply.

Comment: Implicit in this answer is the fact that most "formulas" we write down tend to be continuous, so in light of the first paragraph, we're unlikely to be able to do so with a formula. (Precisely defining just what constitutes a "formula" is not straight forward, which is why this claim is pretty hand wavey.)